# Setting env var in NSIS, not visible in program launched from installer

Tags: environment-variables, nsis

I'm setting permanent environment variables from an NSIS installer like described in the [NSIS wiki](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Setting_Environment_Variables). That works as expected, the variable is available to *new processes* after the installation.

However, when using the option to launch the installed program at the end of the installation, the environment variable is **not available for that program started from the installer**. I assume this is because the program started there has the installer process as parent and gets the same environment block (see the lpEnvironment argument of the [createProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function).

How can I make the program started from the last page of the installer see the newly set environment variable? Writing a custom launch function instead? The documentation does not say anything about the environment block of the `Exec` function.

Comment: Can you not make the parent NULL when creating the process?

Comment: I do not create the process myself, that is hidden in the magic of NSIS core functionality somewhere. And that is also only a guess of what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to use the Setting Environmental Variables Temporarily code if you want child processes to inherit the (updated) environment because only explorer.exe responds to the WM_WININICHANGE notification.

```
outfile "test.exe"
name "run env test"
requestexecutionlevel user
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "cmd.exe"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_PARAMETERS  "/k set foobar"
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section
System::Call 'Kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "FooBar",t "BazBlargh")i'
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Great. I was so focused on that "set them permanent" alternative, that I completely overlooked this rather obvious solution of using *both*.